# Java SE6 32 bit on a Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: java, macos

My Mac OS X allows me to choose among J2SE 1.4.2 32bit, J2SE 5 32bit, J2SE 5 64 bit and Java SE 6 64bit but it doesn't include the Java SE 6 32bit: does anybody know how can I install this version, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't support 32-bit Java SE 6, but you might look at [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/).

Addendum: You might experiment with the [`java -d32`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/) option.

> -d32, -d64
>
> > Specifies whether the program is to be run in a 32-bit or 64-bit
> >     environment if available.
> >
> > Currently, only the Java HotSpot Server VM supports 64-bit oper-
> >     ations and the -server option is implicit with the use of -d64 .
> >     This is subject to change in a future release.
> >
> > If  neither -d32 nor -d64 is specified, the default is to run in
> >     a 32-bit environment, except for 64-bit only systems.   This  is
> >     subject to change in a future release.

Comment: No, it's not like this, SnowLeopard actually includes the Java SE6 32 bit (besides the other version I also have)...

Comment: Interesting. I was referring to Mac OS X 10.5.8, mentioned in your title.

Comment: Under 10.6 the -d32 switch selects a 32 bit client jvm. -d64 selects a 64 bit server jvm.